# How do I keep chart.js charts in one JS file, and not get errors when the ID from the JS file don't exist on one specific html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, chart.js

I'm quite new with JS, and have a problem with Chart.js and multiple charts.

- I load all libraries like jquery and chart.js from CDNs
- Then I have one plugins.js for localy loaded plugins
- And one js called main.js with all the custom JS.

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

**My question is:**

How do I keep all my Chart.js charts in one .js file, that get loaded on all website pages, but not all pages contains all charts.

(I have a site that consists on multiple pages with different charts, and I'm thinking it's smarter to load all at once in one JS-file)

Appreciate any other pointers also. :)

### -

**About the code**

I've posted the code below and also created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NoLooseEnds/1pt3m41a/

In the main.js I have all my Chart.js data like so (among other things):

```
// *************************************
// Chart.js
// *************************************

// Global Settings
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "rgba(43,43,43,1)";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'ApexNew-Medium', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
// Disable click on legend
Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();

// Bar Charts settings
var barChart__options = {
};

// Doughnut settings
var dnutChart__options = {
  legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    // Disable click on legend
    onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()
  }
};

// *************************************
// Datasets
// *************************************

// Bar Chart X
var barChartX__data = {
  labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"],
  datasets: [
    {
        label: "2015",
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(43,43,43,1)",
        data: [410,430,110]
    },
    {
        label: "2016",
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(233,131,0,1.0)",
        data: [405,360,150]
    }
  ]
};

const barChartX = $("#barChartX");
let ChartX = new Chart(barChartX, {
  type: "bar",
  data: barChartX__data,
  options: barChart__options
});

// Doughnut Chart Y
var dnutChartY__data = {
  labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Points",
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(43,43,43,1)", "rgba(233,131,0,1.0)"],
      data: [90,270]
    }
  ]
};

const dnutChartY = $("#dnutChartY");
let ChartY = new Chart(dnutChartY, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: dnutChartY__data,
  options: dnutChart__options
});



// Doughnut Chart Z
var dnutChartZ__data = {
  labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Points",
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(233,131,0,1.0)","rgba(239,162,64,1.0)","rgba(244,193,127,1.0)"],
      data: [405,360,150]
    }
  ]
};

const dnutChartZ = $("#dnutChartZ");
let ChartZ = new Chart(dnutChartZ, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: dnutChartZ__data,
  options: dnutChart__options
});
```

And my HTML like so:

```
<div class="example__chart">
  <div>
    <canvas id="barChartX" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
  </div>
<!--  
  <div>
    <canvas id="dnutChartY" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
  </div> 
-->
  <div>
    <canvas id="dnutChartZ" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

*As you can see I have commented out a part to trigger the error.*

Comment: use try-catch have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/1pt3m41a/4/

Comment: @Manish 
Thank you, but it seems like your fix triggers the chart (yey), but it still produces the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" error.

Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper function and check whenever the DOM element exists for the `barChartX`, `dnutChartY`, `dnutChartZ` or any other DOM element like this:

```
var doChart = function(o, d) {
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined' && o.length > 0) {
        return new Chart(o, d);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Then your Chart.js code will be like this**

```
// *************************************
// Chart.js
// *************************************
// Global Settings
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "rgba(43,43,43,1)";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'ApexNew-Medium', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
// Disable click on legend
Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();


var doChart = function(o, d) {
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined' && o.length > 0) {
        return new Chart(o, d);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// Bar Charts settings
var barChart__options = {};

// Doughnut settings
var dnutChart__options = {
    legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        // Disable click on legend
        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()
    }
};

// *************************************
// Datasets
// *************************************

// Bar Chart X
var barChartX__data = {
    labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"],
    datasets: [{
            label: "2015",
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(43,43,43,1)",
            data: [410, 430, 110]
        },
        {
            label: "2016",
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(233,131,0,1.0)",
            data: [405, 360, 150]
        }
    ]
};

const barChartX = $("#barChartX");
/*let ChartX = new Chart(barChartX, {
  type: "bar",
  data: barChartX__data,
  options: barChart__options
});*/

let ChartX = doChart(barChartX, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartX__data,
    options: barChart__options
});

// Doughnut Chart Y
var dnutChartY__data = {
    labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Points",
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(43,43,43,1)", "rgba(233,131,0,1.0)"],
        data: [90, 270]
    }]
};

const dnutChartY = $("#dnutChartY");
let ChartY = doChart(dnutChartY, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: dnutChartY__data,
    options: dnutChart__options
});

// Doughnut Chart Z
var dnutChartZ__data = {
    labels: ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Points",
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(233,131,0,1.0)", "rgba(239,162,64,1.0)", "rgba(244,193,127,1.0)"],
        data: [405, 360, 150]
    }]
};

const dnutChartZ = $("#dnutChartZ");
let ChartZ = doChart(dnutChartZ, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: dnutChartZ__data,
    options: dnutChart__options
});
```

Please check my working example with no javascript errors here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/chartsjs/

**UPDATE**

Please have a look at the JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/h1dafqjx/2/

**UPDATE 2**

**Problem analysis and solution**

The problem you are facing, is that you want to have multiple declarations and chart setups in one javascript file that you are going to use on many location which may happen some of these locations do not have some of the declared elements, thus you want your code to handle those cases.

You declare a chart like this:

```
const barChartX = $("#barChartX");
let ChartX = new Chart(barChartX, {
  type: "bar",
  data: barChartX__data,
  options: barChart__options
});
```

In order to handle a missing DOM element, like when the `$("#barChartX")` does not exists, you need to create a condition to check those cases.

For excample:

```
const barChartX = $("#barChartX");
if(typeof(barChartX) != 'undefined' && barChartX.length > 0) {
    let ChartX = new Chart(barChartX, {
      type: "bar",
      data: barChartX__data,
      options: barChart__options
    });
}
```

With the obove code, you check if the `barChartX` is defined and if it actually contains any elements with the `barChartX.length > 0` condition.
Now, in order to do not repeat things, we keep it simple and do all that checking in a function. Thus we create the function `doChart` like this:

```
var doChart = function(o, d) {
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined' && o.length > 0) {
        return new Chart(o, d);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The first parameter `o` is the DOM element we want to check and the second parameter `d` is the chart object properties.

For example:

```
let ChartX = doChart(barChartX, {
  type: "bar",
  data: barChartX__data,
  options: barChart__options
});
```

Here we pass to the `doChart` function the `barChartX` jQuery object of the element in order for the function to check if exists. Then we pass the chart object parameters by the second parameter named `d`, which is the chart object properties for creating the new chart:

```
{
  type: "bar",
  data: barChartX__data,
  options: barChart__options
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer!

I see you have commented out a bit of the javascript also? Doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose?

The point is to keep the .js file as is on all website pages (so you just load it once on the first load), and then as you visit different pages it loads different charts from the .js file.

Comment: @nle You can remove the commented code. The function I created `doChart` does exactly what the commented code, but it first check if the DOM element exists and then it creates a `new Chart`. It's really safe and you can try to create more chart objects to test if it's working,

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get the "type:", "data:" and "options:"  implemented in the code? 

EDIT: And sorry if it obvious, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: You pass that javascript object to the `doChart` function in its second parameter: `doChart = function(o, d)`; the first `o` is the DOM element for the function to check if exists and then the `d` parameter is the object that contains the `"type"`, `"data"` and `"options"` properties.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Would you be so kind and create a new fiddle from mine, because I still don't understand. :/ https://jsfiddle.net/NoLooseEnds/1pt3m41a/ ?

Comment: @nle Of course. Please have a look at my updated answer. EDIT: Do you want me to write a small explanation on how the function works?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, if you don't mind, please do. I'll hopefully get some more learning out of it.

Comment: @nle Please check my updated answer for the problem/solution and how the function works explanation.

Comment: Awesome! I _really_  appreciate your help! You my friend are a standup guy! :)